# Is there a way to clear the error message when trying to run an app on android studio via usb debugging?

Tags: android, debugging, android-instant-apps

I get the error message ***"Error while uploading and launching Instant app"*** when I tried running my app to a mobile device

Comment: Do you mean clearing the Logcat console ?

Comment: I actually wanted to run the app on my andriod device and it showed that error message.

Comment: are you able to run your app in debug on your android device ?

Comment: I was able to run it at first, the subsequent one was the one that showed the error message

Answer (score 0):

I guess by Instant app you mean applying code changes without restarting the app.

Sometimes, it is not possible, for example if you make a change to the app manifest or a resource referenced by the manifest.

In these cases, you need to restart the activity using the button

**"Apply Changes and Restart Activity"** (in Android Studio 3.6)

or restart the full app using the **"Debug" (or "Run")**  button, which forces a cold swap and an app restart.

Comment: I tried again. My app now runs on the mobile, but the error message persists.

Comment: what version of Android Studio do you use ? Which button did you use to run the app ?

Comment: my version is Android 3.3.2

Comment: Can you upgrade to version 3.6 and use the Debug button (or Maj+F9) to launch your app ?